# What is the loopback interface lo0 on Macs?

Tags: network, security, firewall

What is the loopback interface `lo0` on Macs? What's the use of it? Does it have any vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loopback is a virtual interface that is an integral part of all TCP/IP network interfaces on all generally available operating systems. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback):

> Any traffic that a computer program sends to a loopback IP address is
>   simply and immediately passed back up the network software stack as if
>   it had been received from another device.

Since loopback interfaces don't send data anyplace but back from where they came you will not **generally** find ways to hack a system using loopback. That does not mean it can't or has not been done but it is not something to generally worry about.